# Hide specific text in a class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have two links in the same class, but only need to remove one of them.

```
<table class="LinksTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="LinksTableFormat">
<tr>
<td>
<a class="LinksText" href="Default.aspx?Page=Shopping Cart Upload">Shopping Cart Upload</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="LinksText" href="default.aspx?page=admin page">Admin</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The Admin link is set to only show when certain users sign into the site, but Shopping Cart Upload shows to any user. I need to remove the Shopping Cart Upload link without affecting the Admin link.

Is there any way to do this with jQuery, since they are both in the same class?

Comment: What have you tried. Surely this is better to do server side with access control/permission.

Comment: if the upload link will always be the first link you can: $(".LinksText:first").remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try with selectors:

```
$('.LinksText:first').hide(); or .remove()
```

or

```
$('.LinksText:last').hide() or .remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$(".LinksText[href*='Shopping']").remove();
```

Comment: I ended up using the other answer this time, but this one worked too! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fair enough.  Just be aware that `:first` and `:last` will be a relatively fragile solution, as it won't tolerate adding new links or rearranging them.

Comment: Oh, good point. I don't plan to add any links, but will keep that in mind for sure. Thanks!